# How to change color of a select on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am trying to create a form. I am using a `<datalist>` tag as well as an `<input>` tag, so that a user can also type an option or just select an option by clicking on these. I would like to make a user to make use of the input in order to search for an option. I would like for this option to continually  change color on keypress.

**Example:**

When an option is available stating "Hello" and the user starts typing the first couple characters (e.g. "He"), the typed in part should become bold and the "Hello" option related to it should be detected.

Is it possible to achieve this using jQuery and if so, how could I do this?

```html
<div class="cargo blocos">
  <label class="titulos">Cargo</label>
  <input class="custom-select" type="text" list="cargos" placeholder="Ex: Analista de Banco de Dados" required />
  <span class="invalid-feedback">Cargo é obrigatório</span>
  <datalist id="cargos">
    <option>Analista de RH</option>
    <option>Analista de Marketing</option>
  </datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: Please also add what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

This code should work but remember you are using a datalist element and it cannot be styled via css neither forced by js. If you want to style some parts of an option element, use a select element instead of datalist.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('.custom-select').on('keyup', function() {
    checkValues($(this).val());
  });
});

function checkValues(val) {
  var options = $('#cargos option');
  var valLength = val.length;
  $('#cargos option').each( function() {
    var begins = $(this).text().indexOf(val);
    $(this).html(begins === 0 ? '<strong>' + $(this).text() + '</strong>' : $(this).text());
  })
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="cargo blocos">
      <label class="titulos">Cargo</label>
      <input class="custom-select" type="text" list="cargos" placeholder="Ex: Analista de Banco de Dados" required />
      <span class="invalid-feedback">Cargo é obrigatório</span>
            <datalist id="cargos">
                 <option>Analista de RH</option>
                  <option>Analista de Marketing</option>
                  <option>Retrasado de Marketing</option>
             </datalist>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
//short but fast use objet
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>index</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>text</h1>
</body>
<script>
    let text = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0]
    let change = {
        r: "red",
        b: "blue",
        y: "yellow",
        g: "green",
        o: "orange"
    }
    document.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
        let color = e.key
        text.style.color = change[color]


    })
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this is full version